# Google analytics API PHP Get data tablet/phone/deskop

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I have also attached API and now I am able to acquire data type. Returning Visitor New Visitor etc .. But I can not pull the data on the device, whether on mobile, tablet.

I'm confused how to write something also Expoler I could not find it.

```
    public function getResultsGraph1() {
    return $this->analytics->data_ga->get(
                    'ga:' . $this->accounts, $this->startDate, $this->endDate, 'ga:sessions', array(
                'metrics' => 'ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate'));
}
```

Any advice on how to get to it?

Comment: Please use only English here.

Comment: Yes, sorry for main english :-( is bad

Comment: I use Core Reporting API

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dimension [ga:deviceCategory](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_devicecategory) will return desktop, tablet, or mobile.

```
 $optParams = array(
      'dimensions' => 'ga:deviceCategory');

  return $service->data_ga->get(
      TABLE_ID,
      '2010-01-01',
      '2010-01-15',
      'ga:sessions',
      $optParams);
```

Comment: Thnaks :) Now is perfect